# ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaGeolocationProvider <- $cordovaGeolocation <- AgeCtrl

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am currently in the starting phase of building an app via Ionic. Right now i want to implement the cordova geolocation in it. However this keeps giving an error when opening it. For testing purposes i use ionic serve and check it in localhost.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'ui.router'])
.controller('AgeCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $http, $cordovaGeolocation) {


$scope.toggleItem = function (item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
};

$scope.items = [
  { id: '0-12' },
  { id: '12-18' },
  { id: '18-30' },
  { id: '30-65' },
  { id: '65+' }
];

    $scope.time = Date.now();
   $scope.weather = $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Amsterdam&units=metric&APPID=...").then(function(resp) {
   console.log("success", resp);
   }, function(err) {
    console.log("error");
   })

var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
$cordovaGeolocation
.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)

.then(function (position) {
  var lat  = position.coords.latitude
  var long = position.coords.longitude
  console.log(lat + '   ' + long)
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
});

$scope.Confirm = function (){
    $state.go('home');
}
})
```

Is there any place i have made a mistake which causes this problem?

Comment: Did you add the plugin properly to the app?

Comment: Have also made a new project and tried it there. Running it again shows "plugin cordova-plugin-geolocation already installed on android"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not referenced as `$cordovaGeolocation` in ionic. Try `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Ionic serve only emulates the application in the browser.
You do not get access to the Cordova plugins within the browser.

To get the libraries included you need to run the app on the device after adding a specific platform depending on what device you have.

For iOS:

> Ionic platform add ios

For android:

> ionic platform add android

After the platforms are added you can build and run on device using the following command

For iOS:

> ionic run iOS

For android:

> ionic run android

Comment: Unfortunately i have problems running it directly. I have tried making an APK of it and directly installing it on my phone, unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: There are 3 other possibilities: 1. Run it in visual studio 2015 with cross platform tools it has built in emulators for location and motion with Ripple. 2. Try load your app to ionic.io and then download it into the "ionic view" application. 3. Building it as a package and running it on a native emulator with the APK.

Comment: When running it on your phone (android I assume) did you have developer mode on and usb debugging active

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with your ngCordova  installation . 
do below steps -

1- install -------------->  bower install ngCordova

2-  include in index.html above cordova.js ------------------>  script   src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"

3-  inject ------------->   angular.module(starter, ['ngCordova'])

run IONIC serve and issue will be gone .. If it still shows error that /dist/ngCordova is not present then go to location manually where ng cordova is installed and  copy  it to the path e.g. - /lib/ngCordova/dist/...

it will definitely resolve your issue