# Unknown provider: $cordovaGeolocationProvider

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently in the starting phase of building an app weather via Ionic. Right now i want to implement the cordova geolocation ,i have error `Unknown provider: $cordovaGeolocationProvider <- $cordovaGeolocation` i try to fixed but unsuccessfully , However this keeps giving an error when opening it. For testing purposes i use ionic serve and check it in localhost.

my code

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app.weather', ['ionic'])

        .factory('Weather', function($q, $http) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            function getCurrentWeather(lat, lng) {
                var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast//' + lat + ',' + lng + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
                $http.jsonp(url)
                    .success(deferred.resolve)
                    .error(deferred.reject);

                return deferred.promise;
            }

            return {
                getCurrentWeather: getCurrentWeather
            };
        })
        .controller('WeatherCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, Weather) {
            $scope.loading = true;

            $scope.toCelsius = function(temperature) {
                return ((temperature - 32) / 1.8).toFixed(1);
            };

            $cordovaGeolocation
                .getCurrentPosition({
                    timeout: 10000,
                    enableHighAccuracy: false
                })
                .then(function(position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    var long = position.coords.longitude;

                    Weather.getCurrentWeather(lat, long).then(function(data) {
                        $scope.weatherInfo = data;
                        $scope.loading = false;
                    }, function(error) {
                        //TODO Display error message
                    });
                }, function(err) {
                    //TODO Display error message
                });
        });
})();
```

code html

```
<ion-view title="الرئيسية" id="page2" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" class=" ">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <ion-pane>
<div ng-controller="WeatherCtrl as weatherCtrl">
 <div ng-show="loading">
                Carregando informações...
            </div>
            <div ng-hide="loading">
                <p>
                    Temperatura: {{toCelsius(weatherInfo.currently.temperature)}}º
                </p>
                <p>
                    Sensação térmica: {{toCelsius(weatherInfo.currently.apparentTemperature)}}º
                </p>
            </div>
                        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36158618/5059916

Comment: have you included `ng-cordova` file ?

Answer (score 8):

add 'ngCordova' in your module like

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app.weather', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
```

then add ngcordova.min.js file link into your index.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `ngCordova` or `Ionic Native` installed, otherwise you cannot use `$cordovaGeolocation` as it is a wrapper defined in either one of these libraries.

You can find instructions on how to install `ngCordova` [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) and [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/) for `Ionic Native`. There is also a recent article about `Ionic Native` [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/) that might be of interest.

Also keep in mind that a majority of the Cordova plugins do not work in the browser, so you may need to test on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the $cordovaGeolocation plugin?

$cordovaGeolocation description:http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/

If not, you can install it by:
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`

Answer (score 0):

$cordovaGeolocation functionality, along with any other native functionality can only be used in an emulator or on a device. If you serve the app from the browser, it cannot interface with the plugin and is therefore undefined.